# How to get the behaviour like below image for Swift 3.0 iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, shadow

I want to add a shadow on UITabBarController's View Controller's View. Anyone have any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this way you add showdon to your tab bar

```
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage(named:"YOURIMAGE")
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage(named:"YOURIMAGE")
```

In detail you can find this code helpful

```
    tabBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    tabBar.translucent = false
    tabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
    tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

You can try this to apply shadow effect to child view of main view i.e. tabview controller.

```
    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9
    self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    self.view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

Please try it if it helps.

Comment: This works perfect if we want to give shadow to tabbar. But I need shadow on ViewController's view of tabbar items. Tabbar will be under view controller.